# Finding the PDF of a new random variable.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $f_{X,Y}$ be the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ given by
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
2e^{-x - 2y},  & \text{if $x>0$ and $y>0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases} $$
and Z be the random variable defined as $Z = X + Y$. Find the probability density function of Z.

I can solve this by using the Jacobian method, but I want to know how to solve this using the basic definition. I began as
$F_Z(z) = P(Z \le z) $. Can you please explain how to continue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: **Hint** $P(Z\le z)=\int P(X\le z-y \cap Y=y)dy$.

Comment: @awllower Can you please explain more...? I didn't get it.

Comment: Sorry, my answer does not correspond well to the comment. Hope you can take it from here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $X>0$  and $Y>0$ a.s. Then $Z=X+Y>0$ a.s. Therefore
$$F_Z(z)=\int\int_{A_z}2e^{-x-2y}dxdy$$
where $A_z=\{(x,y): z>0, x>0,y>0,x+y\le z\}$. On other words
$A_z=\{(x,y): 0<x<z; 0<y<z-x\}$. Now we have
$$F_Z(z)=\int\int_{A_z}2e^{-x-2y}dxdy\int_0^z\left[\int_0^{z-x}2e^{-x-2y}dy\right]dx$$
$$=2\int_0^ze^{-x}\left[\int_0^{z-x}e^{-2y}dy\right]dx=2\int_0^ze^{-x}\left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2y}|_0^{z-x}\right]dx$$
$$=-\int_0^ze^{-x}\left[e^{-2(z-x)}-1\right]dx=-\int_0^z(e^{-2z+x}-e^{-x})dx$$
$$=-e^{-2z}\int_0^ze^xdx+\int_0^ze^{-x}dx=-e^{-2z}(e^z-1)-(e^{-z}-1)$$
$$=e^{-2z}-2e^{-z}+1=(1-e^{-z})^2, \ \ z>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_z=\{(x,y)|x+y\le z\}$.
Then $$F_Z(z)=\iint\limits_{A_Z}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dydx\overset{y=v-x}{=}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z}f(x,v-x)dvdx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{z}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,v-x)dxdv.$$
So the density should be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,z-x)dx$, as seen by differentiating the integral.
Any error should be pointed out, and every comment is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Notice that, in integrating, we should stay in the region where both $x$ and $z-x$ are positive, in accordance with the definition of $f$. Thanks go to Abhra Abir Kundu for pointing this out.

Comment: If demanded, I could integrate it out explicitly.

Comment: Here $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,v-x)dx=\int_{0}^{v}f(x,v-x)dx$.  As the random variable $X,Y$ are non negative.

Comment: Yes, but I think it should be left completed by OP, as it depends uopn the behaviour of $f$. Regards.

Comment: Ofcourse it depends upon the behaviour of $f$. I just commented so that OP doesnot the make the mistake of integrating the function over the whole real line with the value $(2e^{-x-2y})$.(I personally have made this mistake several times :P)

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Its clear that X and Y are Independent R.V's, so pdf of Z is convolution if pdf's of X and Y. You get the Answer as $$ f_Z(z)= 2\left(e^{-z}-e^{-2z}\right)u(z)$$

Comment: @Ekaveera Thanks for pointing this out. It is also a ood way of doing this, while I think elementary methods suffice.